# react-select validation error message not disapear afeter chage value in Formik and Yup

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I am using react-select to select multiple options. I used `Formik and Yup` for validation. all things work correctly, but the `error message` does not disappear when I select an option.
how can I handle this?

**This is validation:**

```
const [initialValues, setIntialValues] = useState({.......,productLine: "",...});
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
   ..............,
   productLine: Yup.string().required("This field is required"),
   .............
})
const [selectedPrduct, setSelectedProduct] = useState("");
const handleProductChange = selectedPro => {
   setSelectedProduct(selectedPro);
};
```

**and my form:**

```
<Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    onSubmit={(values) => onSubmit(values)}
    enableReinitialize={true}
  >
    {({ errors, values, touched, setValues }) => (
      <Form className="w-full px-3 py-10 space-y-8 divide-y divide-gray-200 text-justify ">
      ..............
      <Select
        value={selectedPrduct}
        styles={{
          input: (base) => ({
            ...base,
            'input:focus': {
              boxShadow: 'none',
            },
          }),
        }}
        onChange={selectedOption => {
          handleProductChange(selectedOption);
        }}
        isSearchable={true}
        options={productLine}
        name="productLine"
        
      />
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="ml-3 inline-flex w-2/4 md:w-20 lg:w-20 justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md bg-magento text-alabaster"
      >
              Save
            </button>
   </Form>
   )}
</Formik>
```

[image]